# css apresenta erro no chorme

Tags: css, css3

Nessa pagina, http://www.magicforbaby.com.br/contato.php?form, os campos do formulário estão estilizados corretamente.

Localmente com os inputs texts está tudo como deve estar, mas na web está fora e os css estão corretamente postados.

Porque será? Detalhe: apenas no Firefox esse erro não ocorreu!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

contato.php

```
<?php require_once "config.php" ; ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><?php echo $constantes->getTituloSite(); ?></title>
    <?php  require_once("_global/_meta/meta.ini"); ?>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="_img/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_global/_css/estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_global/_css/site.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_global/_css/menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_global/_css/jHtmlArea.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="_global/_js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_global/_js/jHtmlArea-0.8.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_global/_js/validaContato.js"></script>    
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="_global/_js/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <!--[endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

      <div class="topo">
        <div class="sessoes">
          <div class="logo"><img src="_img/logo.png" /></div>
          <div class="menu"><?php require_once "_required/menu.php"; ?></div>    
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="conteudo">
        <div class="sessoes"><?php require_once "contatoConteudo.php"; ?></div>
      </div> 

      <div class="base">
        <div class="sessoes"><?php require_once "_required/base.php"; ?></div>
      </div> 
      <div class="final">
        <div class="sessoes"><?php require_once "_required/final.php"; ?></div>
      </div> 

  </body>

</html>
```

contatoConteudo.php

```
<?php if(isset($_GET["form"]) ) {   ?>

  <h1 class="h1Centralizado">Fale Conosco</h1>

  <form class="formularios" style="width: 450px; text-align:center" id="contato" action="?" method="post"> 

    <div class="contatoEsquerdo">  

      <label class="labelPequeno" >Assunto</label><select style="width: 212px; height:52px;" id="assunto" name="assunto" required>
        <option value="">Escolha o assunto</option>
        <option value="1">Quero Comprar</option>
        <option value="2">Quero Vender</option>
        <option value="3">Indicação</option>
        <option value="4">Elogio</option>
        <option value="5">Pedido de Catálogo</option>
        <option value="6">Outro</option>
      </select><br /><br />

      <div class="qual" style="display:none">
          <label class="labelPequeno" >Qual?</label><input type="text" class="typeTextMedio" maxlength="200" id="qual" name="qual" /> <br /> <br />        
      </div>

      <label class="labelPequeno" >Nome</label><input type="text" class="typeTextMedio" maxlength="200" id="nome" name="nome" required /> <br /> <br />

        <label class="labelPequeno" >Telefone</label><input type="tel" class="typeTextMedio" maxlength="14" id="telefone" name="telefone" /> <br /> <br />

      <label class="labelPequeno" >Email</label><input type="email" class="typeTextMedio" required maxlength="200" id="email" name="email" /> <br /><br />

    </div>     

    <div class="contatoDireito">  
      <h1 style="text-align:center; width:100%;">Descrição</h1><br />
      <textarea class="textarea" name="descricao" id="descricao" cols="60" rows="15"></textarea><br /> <br />
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both; width:100%; text-align:center;">
      <input name="envia" class="btnAcesso" type="submit" value="Enviar" /><br /> <br />
    </div>

  </form>

<?php } ?>


<?php

  if(isset($_POST["envia"]) )  {   


    $assunto = $phpUtil->contatoTipos($_POST["assunto"]);  

    require_once "_controlls/_models/Emails.php";
    require_once "_controlls/_daos/EmailsDao.php";
    $emailsDao = new EmailsDao($conexao);

    $email = new Emails(
                     date("Y-m-d"), 
                     "n", 
                     $_POST["nome"], 
                     $_POST["email"], 
                     preg_replace( '#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST["telefone"] ),  
                     "", 
                     $_POST["assunto"], 
                     $_POST["descricao"]);

    $emailsDao->cadastrar($email);

    $texto  = "<h2>Email enviado pelo site da ".$constantes->getTituloSite()."</h2><br />";
    $texto .= "<b>Nome:</b> ".$_POST["nome"]."<br /><br />";
    $texto .= "<b>Telefone:</b> ".$_POST["telefone"]."<br /><br />";
    $texto .= "<b>E-mail:</b> ".$_POST["email"]."<br /><br />";
    $texto .= "<b>Intersse:</b> ".$assunto."<br /><br />";
    $texto .= "<b>Descrição:</b><br />".nl2br($_POST["descricao"])."<br />";

    require_once "_controlls/_models/EmailEnviar.php";
    require_once "_controlls/_daos/EmailEnviarDao.php";

    $emailEnviar = new EmailEnviar( 
          $constantes->getTituloSite(), 
          $constantes->getEmailSite(),
          $_POST["nome"], 
          $_POST["email"],
          "Re: ".$assunto,
          $texto
    );

    $emailEnviarDao = new EmailEnviarDao();

    $enviarEmail = $emailEnviarDao->enviaEmail($emailEnviar);   

    if ($enviarEmail["success"] == 0) {

        echo $phpUtil->sucesso ("Mensagem enviada com sucesso!"); 

    }
    else {

        echo $phpUtil->erro ($enviarEmail["errors"]);   

    }

  }

?>
```

estilo.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-size: 12px;
}
.carregando {
    background: #ffffff;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: verdana;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.carregando img {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 10001;
}
.meio {
    display: none;
}
.sessoes {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.formularios {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
    border: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
a, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset] {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.typeTextGrande, .typeTextMedio, .typeTextPequeno {
    height: 36px;
    padding: 4px;
}
.typeTextPequeno {
    width: 100px;
}
.typeTextMedio {
    width: 200px;
}
.typeTextGrande {
    width: 550px;
}
label {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.labelPequeno {
    width: 100px;
}
.labelMedio {
    width: 200px;
}
.labelGrande {
    width: 300px;
}
.h1Centralizado, .h1CentralizadoAvisos {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.textoPrincipal, .sucesso, .erro {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
.erro, .h1CentralizadoAvisos {
    color: #F00;
}
.clearBoth {
    clear: both;
}
.btnAcesso, .btnPesquisa {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    width: 208px;
    height: 44px;
}
.btnAcesso {
    background-image: url(../../_img/acesso.png);
}
.btnPesquisa {
    background-image: url(../../_img/pesquisar.png);
}
/*///////////////////////// INICIO LISTAGENS ///////////////*/
.lista {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
select {
    width: 110px;
    height: 50px;
}
ul.listaTopo, ul.listaRegistros {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.listaTopo {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
ul.listaTopo li, ul.listaRegistros li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*///////////////////////// FIM LISTAGENS /////////////////*/


@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:860px) {
.sessoes {
    width: 100%;
}
.sucesso, .erro, .h1Centralizado, {
 line-height:100px;
}
}
```

site.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.topo, .menu, .conteudo, .cont, .base, .final {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.logo, .menu {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 150px;
}
.logo {
    width: 10%;
}
.menu {
    width: 89%;
}
.banner {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 657px;
}
.listaCategorias {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.listaCategorias li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 350px;
}
.sobre {
    margin:0 auto; 
    width: 80%;
}
.base {
    background-color: #FCB412;
    border-top: 5px #FC0000 solid;
    border-bottom: 5px #FC0000 solid;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.baseEsquerda {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 3% auto;
    padding: 5px;
}
.barraBase {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.barraBase .hr {
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #FC0000;
    border: none;
}
.baseDireita {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 3% auto;
}
.final {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
.finalEsquerda, .finalDireita {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.finalEsquerda {
    text-align: left;
    width: 700px;
}
.finalDireita {
    text-align: right;
    width: 290px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:860px) {

.listaCategorias li {
    border: #000 .1px solid;
}

.final, .base, .baseEsquerda, .baseDireita, .finalEsquerda, .finalDireita {
    width: 95%;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.barraBase {
    display: none;
}
.final {
    height: 100px;
}
}
```

menu.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.menuPrincipal {
}

.menuPrincipal li {
  display:inline;
}

.menuPrincipal li a {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:19.6%;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: rgb(223,189,92);
}

.menuPrincipal li a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color:rgb(223,189,92);
}


.menuBase li a {
    color:#000;
}

.menuBase li a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:860px) {

.menuAbrir {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
.menuNav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1500;
    background-color:#005E9C;
}

.menuFechar {
    right: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
}

ul.menuPrincipal li a {
    width: 100%;
}

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
.menuAbrir, .menuFechar {
    display: none;
}

ul.menuPrincipal li {
    display: inline;
}
ul.menuPrincipal li a {
    width: 195px;
}
}
```

jhtmlarea.css

```
div.jHtmlArea { display: block; overflow: hidden; border: solid 1px #aaa; background-color: #fff; }

div.jHtmlArea iframe, div.jHtmlArea textarea { border: none;   }

div.jHtmlArea div { display: inline-block; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar { display: inline-block; background: #fbfbfb; border-bottom: solid 1px #aaa; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul { border: solid 1px #ccc; margin: 1px; padding: 1px; float: left; background: #fff url(jHtmlArea_Toolbar_Group_BG.png) repeat-x;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li { list-style-type: none; float: left; border: none; padding: 1px; margin: 1px; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li:hover { border: solid 1px #ccc; background: #ddd url(jHtmlArea_Toolbar_Group__Btn_Select_BG.png); padding: 0; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a { display: block; width: 16px; height: 16px; background: url(jHtmlArea.png) no-repeat -16px -500px; border: none; cursor: pointer; padding: 0px; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.highlighted { border: solid 1px #aaa; background-color: #bbb; padding: 0; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li.separator {height: 16px; margin: 0 2px 0 3px; border-left: 1px solid #ccc;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li.separator:hover { padding: 1px; background-color: #fff; border-top:none; border-bottom:none; border-right:none;}

div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a:hover { }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.bold { background-position: 0 0; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.italic { background-position: -16px 0; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.underline { background-position: -32px 0; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.strikethrough { background-position: -48px 0; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.link { background-position: -64px 0; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.unlink { background-position: -80px 0; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.orderedlist { background-position: -96px 0; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.unorderedlist { background-position: -112px 0; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.image { background-position: -128px 0; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.cut { background-position: -144px 0; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.copy { background-position: -160px 0; }
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.paste { background-position: -176px 0; }

div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.html { background-position: -192px 0; opacity:0.6; filter:alpha(opacity=60);}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.html.highlighted { opacity:1.0; filter:alpha(opacity=100);}

div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.h1 { background-position: 0 -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.h2 { background-position: -16px -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.h3 { background-position: -32px -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.h4 { background-position: -48px -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.h5 { background-position: -64px -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.h6 { background-position: -80px -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.subscript   { background-position: -96px -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.superscript { background-position: -112px -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.indent { background-position: -128px -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.outdent { background-position: -144px -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.horizontalrule { background-position: -160px -16px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.p { background-position: -176px -16px;}


div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.justifyleft { background-position: 0 -32px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.justifycenter { background-position: -16px -32px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.justifyright { background-position: -32px -32px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.increasefontsize { background-position: -48px -32px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.decreasefontsize { background-position: -64px -32px;}
div.jHtmlArea .ToolBar ul li a.forecolor { background-position: -80px -32px;}
```

Comment: Estás a usar algum reset?

Comment: só de margin e padding 0 no *{}

Comment: note que no select não ocorre esse rro

Comment: Coloca o css na pergunta e o html, acho que algo com isset....

Comment: outro detalhe que acabo de observar é que na web, você pode notar, que a pagina está começando um pouco para baixo e para o pessoal do php, esta página é utf-8 sem bom.

Comment: Colocar o código ajuda

Comment: ok, html já foi e o css é grande. Põe ele todo?

Comment: hehe na verdade coloquei errado num é isset é inset

Comment: passou perto, hehehe. Mas não usei inset não. Só no firerfox funciona direito!

Comment: Mano é tanto nome, tinha que ser tudo em português..kkkk

Comment: Mas, sério: notou que há uma diferença na figura nas duas mostras? Que na web, parece que tem alguma coisa tipo que empurrando a página para baixo? Já me certifiquei: não é o BOM do UTF-8.

Comment: O css que tem é esse dentro das tags ou tem outro?

Comment: Você que igual a qual o chrome ou firefox?

Comment: pois é, posso até colocar tudo aqui mas vai ficar enorme. Você não acha melhor acessar a página e ver o código fonte? Mas se achar melhor, posto todo oi código.

Comment: Só o chorme não apresenta o erro. Pronto: coloquei tudo lá!

Comment: A pergunta é se quer igual ao que o chrome apresenta ou o firefox? o input?

Comment: quero igual ao que o firefox apresenta!. Pois só o chorme está diferente. Mas, localmente (localhost), todos os browsers, inclusive o chrome, funcionam corretamente. Por isso postei a figura na pergunta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorre por você não estar "resetando" corretamente o css e cada navegador estar usando um valor padrão diferente.

No caso para ser mais específico o problema está no `box-sizing`, onde no chrome está por padrão como `border-box` e no Firefox está como `content-box`, o que altera o calculo do tamanho do elemento.

No caso se você alterar o seu css adicionando um valor padrão para o `content-box` faz com que fique igual no Chrome e Firefox, não testei em outro navegador

```
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Mas eu recomendaria você a procurar um reset mais completo, pois podem acontecer outros casos de diferenças entre os navegadores

Comment: entendi. Mas me tira uma dúvida. Porque isso só ocorrer na internet. No localhost não está ocorrendo. Veja na imagem. Se o navegador é o mesmo, o comportamento não deveria ser o mesmo? Note que no lado direito a página está sendo empurrada para baixo em relação à página do lado esquerdo!

Comment: É dificil dizer, mas eu diria que ou existe alguma diferença no que está sendo retornado pelo seu servidor de desenvolvimento que faz o Chrome tratar a página de forma diferente ou ele está a tratando de forma diferente simplesmente por estar no localhost

Comment: o problema é que o código fornte (ctrl+u) de ambos é o mesmo!

Comment: Uma coisa que você pode tentar é abrir o Console no Chrome e rodar o comando `document.compatMode` exatamente desta forma, ele vai te retornar o modo de renderização do documento, se estiverem diferentes no seu local e no remoto esse pode ser o problema. E pelo que vi aqui o Chrome me retornou que está no modo `BackCompat` que também é conhecido como `Quirks Mode`, enquanto que o Firefox está retornando `CSS1Compat`, que seria o modo que segue, ou pelo menos tenta, seguir o padrão que todo navegador deveria seguir

Comment: deu certo. Agora vou ler com calma para estudar isso direitinho! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona isso vê se dá certo.

```css
input {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset; 
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset; 
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset;
}
```